# What's the penalty for coaching at the table?

Tags: texas-hold-em

I was playing in home tournament. (However we tend to take the rules seriously.) 
I was attempting to bluff another player that I had position on.(We we're heads up)  I made a pretty big bet and the other player goes into the tank and states that he has a top pair on a board of 2♥5♣9♣5♦. Another player says your ahead then the player jams all in based on that information. Obviously I'm  forced to fold. 
What's the penalty for both player that did the coaching and the player that acted on that information.

Answer (score 4):

Such things are entirely at the discretion of the floorman/tournament director. In a situation as obvious as you describe, I would certainly penalize both players with time away from the table. I am less inclined to return chips or otherwise change the outcome of the hand itself unless I was totally convinced that the player would never have acted that way without interference--and that would require me examining all hands, reconstructing the exact action and what was said when, etc. Without that, if probably have to let the result stand and just enforce the penalty.